# Mutliple Workflos nsted for an Item?

Tags: workflow, infopath, multiple-values, if-condition, email-action

I am currently stuck. I have a form library with multiple days equaling different values. All the columns that I'm using are extracting information from the submitted form. 
I'm trying to have an email sent out to certain individuals when each day equals a certain value.
Example:

If D1 => 750

Send email

If D2 = > 1550

Send email
etc.,

I'm having issues with the workflow trying to send multiple emails for the same day, when I only want 1 to be sent.

```
Step: Step 1
If Current Item:Shift1Copy equals 14:30:00
    Wait for D1FlexTD to be greater than or to equal 750
    Email ******
```

I am using the Shift1 Copy to trigger the email to be sent to a group of individuals that are affected by that shift only, and not everyone.

I am sure this has come up before, and any help is most appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try an else if branch?

```
Wait for Current Item:Shift1Copy to equal 14:30:00
   If D1FlexTD is greater than or equal to 750
     Send email
   Else if D2FlexTD is greater than or equal to 1150
     Send email
```

What do you think?